# cannot cast from json value to orderMap

Tags: json, box2d, libgdx, physics

while trying to test physcis body editor loader (BodyEditorLoader.java) from [here](https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/)

i get this improper casting, below is the function

```
private Model readJson(String str) {
    Model m = new Model();
    OrderedMap<String,?> rootElem 
    = (OrderedMap<String,?>) new JsonReader().parse(str);  //this line has casting problem

    Array<?> bodiesElems = (Array<?>) rootElem.get("rigidBodies");

    for (int i=0; i<bodiesElems.size; i++) {
        OrderedMap<String,?> bodyElem = (OrderedMap<String,?>) bodiesElems.get(i);
        RigidBodyModel rbModel = readRigidBody(bodyElem);
        m.rigidBodies.put(rbModel.name, rbModel);
    }

    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as the new version of libgdx does support Jsonvalue and with [this](https://code.google.com/p/box2d-editor/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Milestone%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=25) help

```
 private Model readJson(String str) {
    Model m = new Model();

    JsonValue map = new JsonReader().parse(str);

    JsonValue bodyElem = map.getChild("rigidBodies");
    for (; bodyElem != null; bodyElem = bodyElem.next()) {
        RigidBodyModel rbModel = readRigidBody(bodyElem);
        m.rigidBodies.put(rbModel.name, rbModel);
    }

    return m;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [`parse` method returns a `JsonValue`](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/JsonReader.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29).

You're probably seeing this mismatch due to a newer build of Libgdx including a not-backwards-compatible change to the JSON code.  See [the blog post](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2993) which includes this:

> Only reading JSON is affected. If you use JsonReader, you’ll get back
>   a JsonValue instead of an OrderedMap.

You can either fix this by updating the code to work with a `JsonValue` or by downgrading to an older version of libgdx (before April 25th).  If you're using nightly builds of Libgdx, definitely pay attention to the CHANGES and keep up with the blog (where most of the big changes are announced).  Otherwise, its probably safer to stick to the "released" versions of Libgdx.